# Cookie not send with fetch in react even though the cookie is set in the browser Firefox or Brave

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, express-session

I am learning and applying authentication with google Oauth2.0, and i am using with passport including express-session to handle login session, however, i am having trouble with Firefox and Brave after deploying, the cookie is not send with the fetch call, i check in the devtool the cookie is set successfully with Oauth callback, but i notice in the request header from my fetch call the cookie is indeed absent. My code settings are as follows:

App js :

```
//require setting
const app = express();

app.use(helmet());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL,
    methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
    credentials: true
}));

app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { 
        secure: "auto",
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2,
        sameSite: "none", //false in developement
    },
    store: pgStore, // this is working
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use("/v1", api);
```

My fetch request from the client side which I use to check if the user is authentificated, I will get the userdata, otherwise i do nothing

```
async function httpGetUser() {
    return await fetch(`${REACT_APP_BASE_URL}/auth/login`, {
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
        }
      })
};
```

Well in Chrome browser looks like it work fine, but if it doesn't work with firefox and brave that mean i must do something wrong and i wasn't able to figure out despite some research on the documentation.

UPDATE2: after fighting with cookie for 3 days: Chrome and Edge work without issue, for some unknown reason even thought the cookie is set on the browser after the callback response header, they're not blocked since i can see them on Brave and Firefox, but i just can't fetch with the credentials on the request header despite checking the sameSite attribut in express-session, cors..

UPDATE3: I manage to make it work with Firefox but it's random, if i clear out the cookie it could stop working but sometimes it rework miraculously.. as for Brave still impossible.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` is a response header, not a request header.